# Can ETW processing be disabled for a .NET5 console application?

Tags: c#, .net-5, etw

I have an `async Main()` like this one:

```
    static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var program = new Program();
            await program.RunAsync();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log(exception);
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

It is a scraper that makes heavy use of `HttpClient`. I use `pwsh` to run 32 instances of the process in parallel and sometimes (after 1000s have been run) one process gets stuck. When I attach VisualStudio to the process, there are no threads with my code, but instead I see this:

[image: Stack trace of two threads]

It seems there is a callback that gets deadlocked waiting for ETW...

How do I fix this? Is there any way I can disable ETW tracing in this case?

Comment: You have looked explicitly in the other threads of the process and not just on the shown stack when you attached the debugger?

Comment: Yes, in this case there were 5 more threads with nothing managed going on in them.